# How have the return of the current date via javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How have the return of the current date via javascript, time-in-class label can use jquery or angular.

The idea is to have the last update date.

If anyone knows I am grateful.

Can not enter the direct value, a feature that at runtime add the date has to be created ..

```
<div class="footer">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <span class="pull-left time-label"></span>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <a href="#" class="toggle-legend visible-lg pull-left cLineSwap">Legend</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying...

Comment: @Derek I want the current date via javascript or angularJS.

Comment: So basically you want the `Date` constructor: `var date = new Date();`

Answer (score 1):

There's a `Date` constructor in JavaScript that when called without arguments, will give you the current time and date:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

In order to help you more, you need to specify what you want to do.

Comment: Agradeço fazer @ NobleMushtak. mas eu quero algo parecido com isto da seguinte forma: <code>function processUpdateKeyword (resposta, categoria) {var lastUpdated = new Date () toString ("MM / dd / aaaa hh: mm tt").; . $ ("#" + Keyword_idDiv + ". Tempo pull-left.verizon-widget-label") html ("Última Atualização:" + lastUpdated); </code>

Comment: Do you want to use `Date.parse`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Answer (score 0):

```
Date.now();   // 1403296571453
```

Or if you want to get a little more fancy/human readable, look into http://momentjs.com/

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // June 20th 2014, 1:37:07 pm
moment().format('dddd');                    // Friday
moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // Jun 20th 14
moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');     // 2014 escaped 2014
moment().format();                          // 2014-06-20T13:37:07-07:00
```

Comment: @ConnorBlackthere is something with angularJS?